# Find if exception exists before attempting to print with traceback.print_stack()

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception, traceback

Is there a way to find out if there is an exception before calling `traceback.print_stack()` in python?

Comment: Um... `try: #code; except Exception: traceback.print_stack()`?

Comment: I'm doing the stacktrace printing at a different level to where an exception is thrown and at that point i don't know if an exception was thrown or not...

Comment: How are you handling the exception?  If an exception is raised and not catched/handled it will get cascaded all the way your stack and end your program before where your `traceback.print_stack()` calls along with its check conditions.  Anyway if you must try, look for [`sys.exc_info`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info)

Answer (score 0):

You can use "try" and "except" methods built into python.
https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html